# Error while running server in django after connecting djangorestframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This error happens after adding rest_framework (pip install djangorestframework) to project but i dont know the reason in this framework or not.

Error log, i think, is not enough informative for me. If need to share any file just let me know.

Note: I am new in django web api so any your advice would be valuable.

Thank you in advance.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup      
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create  
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module        
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)   
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 618, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 603, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 318, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 324, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 364, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 380, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 278, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 1172, in resolve    
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 200, in resolve     
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

**This is settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from datetime import date
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "9gr-03(+aq_#w-2j2*#wge200^#)&td$0w$q3vtonq1m^zdl63"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "tsundoku",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "backend.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/Tsundoku/src/'),
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "backend.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# MEDIA_URL this is for displaying image in browser ex. http://localhost:8000/images/d14f96e4b0e94973b151ea8097e28c01.jpg
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/Tsundoku/src/static'),
)
# MEDIA_ROOT this is the directory where the images will be saved
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, f'static/images/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static/")


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

**Project -> urls.py**

```
"""backend URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('tsundoku.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from .model import Books
from rest_framework import serializers


class BooksSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = ('name', 'writer', 'description')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'username', 'email', 'groups']


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['url', 'name']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from datetime import date
import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

# Create your models here.


class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Writers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,
                            verbose_name="Writer name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def image_name(instance, filename):
    new_name = uuid.uuid4().hex
    filebase, extension = filename.split(".")
    return f"{date.today().year}/{date.today().month}/{date.today().day}/{new_name}.{extension}"


class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name="Book Name", blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=500, verbose_name="Book Description", blank=False
    )
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Writers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    write_date = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, verbose_name="Date", blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default="False", blank=False)
    in_stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=image_name,
        blank=True,
        default="default_book.jpg",
    )
    pages = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    currency = models.CharField(default="AZN", max_length=10)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    last_edit_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Users(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="First Name", max_length=25, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Last Name", max_length=25, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class UserBook(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book.name


class UserAdress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True
    )
    latitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True
    )


class Orders(models.Model):
    user_adress = models.ForeignKey(UserAdress, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**djangorestframework is already installed**

```
$ pip install djangorestframework
Requirement already satisfied: djangorestframework in c:\users\fuadt\onedrive\desktop\python\tsundoku\backend\tsundoku_venv\lib\site-packages (3.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: django>=2.2 in c:\users\fuadt\onedrive\desktop\python\tsundoku\backend\tsundoku_venv\lib\site-packages (from 
djangorestframework) (3.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\fuadt\onedrive\desktop\python\tsundoku\backend\tsundoku_venv\lib\site-packages (from django>=2.2->djangorestframework) (2020.5)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\users\fuadt\onedrive\desktop\python\tsundoku\backend\tsundoku_venv\lib\site-packages (from django>=2.2->djangorestframework) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.2.10 in c:\users\fuadt\onedrive\desktop\python\tsundoku\backend\tsundoku_venv\lib\site-packages (from django>=2.2->djangorestframework) (3.3.1)
(tsundoku_venv)
```

**But it, also, give an error related to rest_framework**

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line    
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 
24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", 
line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\fuadt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in 
_find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in 
_find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

[image: This is structure of project]

Comment: Read the documentation of the library you are installing: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#quickstart. You didn't add 'rest_framework' to your installed apps yet.

Comment: as i already mentioned i have already installed djangorestframework. If have any mistake just point where is mistake.
Note: if you downwoted question i think it is not a right approach. I wrote here to get help. and mentioned if something wrong just tell i will add other files also. anyway thank you.

Comment: Sorry for making that assumption. You only mentioned running pip install and not anything else. The error is pretty standard for if somebody forgot to add it to the INSTALLED_APPS. I will take an extra look later if I can help you

Comment: @ФуадТеймуров You need to install django-rest-framework using pip3, try this, `pip3 install djangorestframework`

Comment: If I uninstall DRF from my own project, but leaving 'rest_framework' in the INSTALLED_APPS I get the exact same error. So it looks like your Django might be outside of your virtual env and that is why it cannot find the module?

Comment: @KaushalSharma reinstalled. Same issue. Also reinstalled venv too.

Comment: @ФуадТеймуров It could be possible that you might have installed rest framework globally and not on venv or maybe vice versa. Try pip freeze globally and in venv to check if it is installed where you want it to be

Comment: actually it did not help too. I rolled back to the working, previous commit and will try to not initiate this problem again. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're setup `rest_framework` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
]
```

Comment: Thank u @anonymoususer, but i did it too. I have shared my settings.py above

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution for my problem, but I did a such mistake also which caused almost the same issue. While development I use multiple terminals and open them before running venv in first, so this causes almost the same issue. I relised this after @Matt's answer. So Be carefull in a such situations. Be patient, live long ))

Note: Wan to mention again, I could not solve this issue, just rolled back to the working commit, reinstalled venv and do everything again. Works like a charm.